# iOS open source build for armv7 , armv7s ,arm64

Tags: ios, xcode, open-source, armv7, libvpx

I am developing an application for iOS device,
and one of the requirement is to make use of libvpx [webM](http://www.webmproject.org), i could able to build it for armv7 architecture, but since has to be universal application, so this should also get it build for armv7s , arm64 architecture too,

now need few clarification,

- Since libvpx doesn't have strong build support for arm64 and armv7s and it seems  arm64 has backward support, so is it sufficient to
  use armv7 library for arm64 and if this is the case, then what should
  be modify in the Xcode project settings,
- or I should keep Xcode project settings as it is, but should modify library configuration using lipo or any other build tool.

In short, i want to know, if any open source which has standard ./configure , make etc... build support for arm7 being there, then how can it be used to support armv7s and arm64 bit architecture.

Answer (score 1):

You can have arm7s support by adding arm7 built library into fat lib as arm7s architecture.
So that your lipo command looks like this:

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -create -arch armv7 ios7/lib/xyz.a -arch armv7s ios7/lib/xyz.a -arch i386 ios7_x86/lib/xyz.a -output xyz.a
```

See that ios7/lib/xyz.a appears twice: once for arm7 and second time as arm7s.

Regarding arm64, not all libraries automatically build for arm64. Especially libraries with lots of optimized assembly code like libvpx.